# FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition

I am making a simple speech_recognition program in python3.6.3
here is the python code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import os

r = sr.Recognizer()
r.energy_threshold = 10000
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print('Say something')
    audio = r.listen(source)
    print("Done")


try:
    text = r.recognize_google(audio)
    print(text)
    os.system("say '"+'I think you said,'+text+'!'+"'")

except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

When I run it I get this error:

OSError:FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC  command line application by running `apt-get install flac or your        operating system's equivalent

The surprising thing is I already have flac installed using brew.
And I checked the flac installation using the terminal like this:
$which flac
/usr/local/bin/flac

this shows that flac is installed but no still being recognized.
I will be my pleasure to have some help with this.

Answer (score 4):

I was trying the same project on a mac M1 and

```
brew install flac
```

solved everything!

Answer (score 3):

The logic in that `speech_recognition` module is [looking first for a `flac` executable in your $PATH](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/19dc36eb6a6173b500e2cc8cf2161ea2fe8cb891/speech_recognition/__init__.py#L1267). Double check on the command-line that `flac` is available:

```
$ which flac
```

This should tell you something like `/usr/local/bin/flac` , if you have installed `flac` with homebrew as you say. If so, make sure this $PATH environment variable is exposed to the Python program you are running. A debug trick to help, stick these lines in your program:

```
path = os.getenv('PATH')
print("Path is: %s" % (path,))
print("shutil_which gives location: %s" % (sr.shutil_which('flac'))
```

which will give you a more definitive clue about why `flac` isn't being picked up.

Comment: Thank you Josh, I get this results                                                        Path is: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
 shutil_which gives location: None . Can you tell me how to solve this. I an new to python and I have nosolution

Comment: Python inherits your `PATH` when you run it. If you start it somewhere where the `PATH` is incomplete, you can run `PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH python3 /path/to/your/script.py` or manipulate `os.environ` in Python.

Comment: see @tripleee 's comment -- if you have `flac` installed via homebrew, it should be under directory `/usr/local/bin/` , so just make sure you run your program with the `PATH` environment variable including this directory, as @tripleee's command shows. Double check that you really have `flac` installed via homebrew with `brew list flac`.

Comment: Thank you all.Now I just did as Tripleee said and it worked. But  is there a way I could get flac into the /usr/local/bin directory or make python look for it in it's present directory instead

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on Windows.

```
print("shutil_which gives location: %s" % (sr.shutil_which('flac')))
```

was returning None

I had to modify the __init__.py in the speech_recognition library

```
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac")  # check for installed version first
```

in

```
flac_converter = shutil_which("flac.exe")  # check for installed version first
```

to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an issue with python finding flac and you already have flac installed with homebrew, then it means flac is probably located in this directory /usr/local/bin while python is looking for it in this directory
usr/bin or usr/sbin. 
First check if flac is installed by running brew list flac.
if it is installed, you will have to run this command in the terminal:

sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/flac /usr/bin. OR
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/flac /usr/sbin
if you do this It might probably work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I searched for flac-mac (In PyCharm) and then changed my preferences from 》
Open matching files in PyCharm. To 》 Open matching files as text and auto-detect file by content.