# Error in Python CGI Speech Recognition API

Tags: python, python-3.x, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

While working on speech recognition project using google speech api in python i am having the following issue while implementing the code on cgi, however, this seems to work completely fine while working as a local project, Unable to resolve the same any help shall be highly appreciated. 
The Following Error Comes when I use Speech Recognition Google API:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:/XAMPP/xampp/cgi-bin/TRY.py", line 76, in <module>
    data = recordAudio()
  File "E:/XAMPP/xampp/cgi-bin/TRY.py", line 31, in recordAudio
    data = r.recognize_google(audio)
  File "C:\Users\BHANU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 828, in recognize_google
    convert_width=2  # audio samples must be 16-bit
  File "C:\Users\BHANU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 445, in get_flac_data
    flac_converter = get_flac_converter()
  File "C:\Users\BHANU\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition\__init__.py", line 1196, in get_flac_converter
    raise OSError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent")
OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737909/flac-conversion-utility-not-available-consider-installing-the-flac-command-lin maybe it will help