# Speech Recognition module in python throwing OSError

Tags: python

I am trying to transcribe text from an audio file with the speech recognition module in python. However, whenever I try to run the code, the module throws an OSError. I have disabled the lines of code that say “try” and “except”, since the code returns “Sorry... run again...” if I don’t. I have made sure that the audio sample is 16 bit, but even then I can’t get it to work. I am running Pythonista on an iPad Air, but I get the same results when using a MacBook Air. Is there a problem with software compatibility? I am also new to python, so can anybody help me with this issue?

The code:

```
#import library
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
import wave


# Initialize recognizer class (for recognizing the speech)
r = sr.Recognizer()

# Reading Audio file as source
# listening the audio file and store in audio_text variable

with sr.AudioFile('audio1.wav') as source:

    audio_text = r.listen(source)

# recoginize_() method will throw a request error if the API is unreachable, hence using exception handling
#try:
    
# using google speech recognition
text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
print('Converting audio transcripts into text ...')
print(text)
 
#except:
     #print('Sorry.. run again...')
```

The Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/34AFF89C-1113-4021-BF04-27338D54F87B/Pythonista3/Documents/program/program.py", line 21, in <module>
text = r.recognize_google(audio_text)
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/34AFF89C-1113-4021-BF04-27338D54F87B/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 828, in recognize_google
convert_width=2  # audio samples must be 16-bit
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/34AFF89C-1113-4021-BF04-27338D54F87B/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 445, in get_flac_data
flac_converter = get_flac_converter()
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/34AFF89C-1113-4021-BF04-27338D54F87B/Pythonista3/Documents/site-packages-3/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 1196, in get_flac_converter
raise OSError("FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent")
OSError: FLAC conversion utility not available - consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac` or your operating system's equivalent
```

Comment: consider installing the FLAC command line application by running `apt-get install flac`

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Anthony. As I mentioned, I am on MacOS so I can not perform that command. I have tried to install flac with homebrew, but the issue still persists. Is there another way to install FLAC command line tools? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you `brew list` and it's there, then maybe check to see if you are over Google's quota for API calls. Possibly that's why it just says to try again

Comment: Thank you, but it’s there in brew’s list of installed formulae. Is Google’s quota for API calls on a daily basis? If so, I don’t think that being over is the issue since I have repeatedly gotten the same error over multiple days.

Comment: It looks like it might be a python path thing, look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49737909/flac-conversion-utility-not-available-consider-installing-the-flac-command-lin)